# Numpy: How to convert colour matrices into a flattened vector

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I am trying to segment a colour image using the Mean Shift algorithm using sklearn. I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('sample_images/fruit_half.png').convert('RGB')
image = np.array(image)

red = image[:,:,2]
green = image[:,:,1]
blue = image[:,:,0]
```

I have read the image and converted it into a numpy array. I have then extracted each colour channel (R,G,B) so that I can use each as a variable for classification.

I want to convert the colour matrices above into a flattened vector, since I want to use it as a variable for classification. E.g. if the original image was 100x100 then the flattened colour sample matrix would be 10000 x 3.

I don't want to convert each matrix into its own vector; I want to all three colour matrices to be made into one flattened vector.

However, I am not sure what methods I can use to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape the array to get the desired effect:

```
img = NP.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype='int')
img[:,:,0] = NP.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100)
img[:,:,1] = 1
img[:,:,2] = 2
```

Flatten the image so each colour is a column (ie. 10000 x 3):

```
img.reshape(-1, 3)
```

Output:

```
array([[    0, 22222, 33333],
       [    1, 22222, 33333],
       [    2, 22222, 33333],
       ...,
       [ 9997, 22222, 33333],
       [ 9998, 22222, 33333],
       [ 9999, 22222, 33333]])
```

To convert to a 3 x 10000 array you can use:

```
img.transpose(2, 0, 1).reshape(3, -1)
```

Output:

```
array([[    0,     1,     2, ...,  9997,  9998,  9999],
       [22222, 22222, 22222, ..., 22222, 22222, 22222],
       [33333, 33333, 33333, ..., 33333, 33333, 33333]])
```